# How to convert Local_Timestamp into UTC Timestamp?

Tags: sql, db2

The Timestamp is the localtime of the DB2 Server.
The date was stored in the time zone Europe / Berlin.

I would like to convert the then stored date to UTC. Is there a way to calculate this in DB2 Dialect?

Comment: Give some example here . your input and expected Output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the  [TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061917.html) scalar function

```
 values TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP'2019-10-01 00:00:00', 'Europe/Berlin')
```

Please note the second parameter is case sensitive.
There is also a FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use the [TIMEZONE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r_sf_timezone.html) function and to use [CURRENT TIMEZONE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0005887.html) as help for the input.

The function converts date and time from one to another timezone. The register CURRENT TIMEZONE gives you the difference between server timezone and UTC.

Answer (score 1):

As @data_henrik pointed out, `CURRENT TIMEZONE` is the special register to use, it can be simply subtracted from `CURRENT TIMESTAMP` e.g.:

```
db2 "values CURRENT TIMESTAMP - CURRENT TIMEZONE"

1                         
--------------------------
2019-10-16-11.36.24.025651

  1 record(s) selected.
```